# Subgrilla en jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

estoy comenzando con jqGrid y me estoy guiando con [jqGrid Demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Lo que necesito es muy similar al ejemplo que aparece en **Advanced -> Master Detail**, solo que necesito que la tabla "Invoice Detail" se desplegue en otra página y no sé como hacer.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "otra página"? Explica un poco mejor tu problema y muestra el código que tengas

Comment: En el ejemplo las 2 grillas se muestran en la misma página, y yo necesito que al seleccionar una fila de la grilla principal la subgrilla se muestre en otra página, es decir otra url. El código es el mismo del ejemplo, solo adapté las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrias es crear un formatter el cual invoca a una funcion donde obtienes un id o dato deseado para obtener el detalle y esta funcion manda a cargar tu subgrid o detalle de grid en otra pagina

```
function getSelectedRow() {
    var grid = $("#jqGrid");
    var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam',"selrow");

    if (rowKey)
        alert("Selected row primary key is: " + rowKey);
    else
        alert("No rows are selected");
}
```

con esa funcion obtienes el id de la fila seleccionada con ello podrias mandara cargar la nueva grid en donde tu deseas si es una nueva venta puedes usar windows.open con javascript
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp